# Correct way to serialize a JPanel?

Tags: serialization, jpanel

I am sending my class which extends JPanel through an ObjectOutputStream to the client, so that their GUI will 'load'.

```
public class ClickOptionPanel extends JPanel implements Serializable {

private Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 13);

private JLabel clickerTitle;

private JSlider clickerMaxSlider, clickerMinSlider;

private JTextField clickerMinField, clickerMaxField;

private JCheckBox clickInsideMinecraft, autoBlock;

public ClickOptionPanel() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(getClickerTitlePanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(getClickerSliderPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(getCheckBoxPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

private JPanel getClickerTitlePanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    clickerTitle = new JLabel("Clicker Options");
    clickerTitle.setFont(font);
    panel.add(clickerTitle);
    return panel;
}

private JPanel getClickerSliderPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    clickerMaxSlider = new JSlider(0, 200, 125);
    clickerMaxSlider.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 45));
    clickerMinSlider = new JSlider(0, 200, 75);
    clickerMinSlider.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 45));
    panel.add(clickerMaxSlider, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(clickerMinSlider, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(getClickFieldPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return panel;
}

private JPanel getClickFieldPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    clickerMaxField = new JTextField(10);
    clickerMaxField.setFont(font);
    clickerMaxField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    clickerMinField = new JTextField(10);
    clickerMinField.setFont(font);
    clickerMinField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panel.add(clickerMinField);
    panel.add(clickerMaxField);
    return panel;
}

private JPanel getCheckBoxPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    clickInsideMinecraft = new JCheckBox("Only click inside of Minecraft:                                                     ");
    clickInsideMinecraft.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    autoBlock = new JCheckBox("Enable auto-block:                                                       ");
    autoBlock.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    panel.add(clickInsideMinecraft, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(autoBlock, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return panel;
}
```

There is the JPanel which I am sending. I create a new instance of it before it is sent.

The JPanel is turning up blank - why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I was doing everything right - it was just that on the client side I forgot to set the ois.readObject object to the panel!